# Titanium Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, signing, required

How can I solve this error?

> Titanium Code signing is required for product type Application in SDK iOS 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Until Titanium supports the newest Xcode, you'll need to downgrade. At this time, 8.1 is the newest supported version.